# Merging a feature branch after a big file move

Tags: git, git-merge

In the beginning, my repo looked like this:

```
master:
    foo/
    bar/
    new-bar/
```

In a feature branch, many commits were added to new-bar:

```
feature:
    foo/
    bar/
    -/
```

And in the master branch, bar was deleted and new-bar was moved into its place with `git mv`:

```
master:
    foo/
    b̶a̶r̶/
    bar/
```

I'd like to merge the feature branch in without causing tons of conflicts:

```
master:
    foo/
    b̶a̶r̶/
    /
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken specific actions that have led to a conflicting situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Release-Notes for git 2.18](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.18.0.txt):

> - Rename detection logic that is used in "merge" and "cherry-pick" has
>     learned to guess when all of x/a, x/b and x/c have moved to z/a,
>     z/b and z/c, it is likely that x/d added in the meantime would also
>     want to move to z/d by taking the hint that the entire directory
>     'x' moved to 'z'.

AFAICT this covers your usecase -- just use a contemporary Git version.

Comment: Beware: this update to the rename-detection logic was buggy and was put in and then backed out several times during development, before the 2.18 release (where it was deemed sufficiently stable). In 2.19, `git am` was modified to make sure it *doesn't* use it, which apparently works around the biggest remaining problem. I don't think any of this really affects the OP's use-case, just note that between 2.18 and 2.19, `git am -3` sometimes gets false hits from this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the choice to rebase your feature branch on top of `master`, the renaming should go fairly well. To be tried. Once the rebase will be done, your branch should be as before, except that all the changes will have been done in `bar/` instead of `new-bar/`.

If you decide to not rebase it, at the top of your feature branch I would add a commit which moves `new-bar/` as `bar/`, so that it is compatible with `master`, then merge it.

In any case you will have to try and see what fits your needs better.